# Is there a way to use one command to draw three lines in one figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, command

By using the following commands, three lines can be shown in one figure. (A, B, C are three functions.)

```
plot(A);  
hold on;  
plot(B);  
hold on;  
plot(C);  
hold off;
```

I wonder if this can be replaced by one command line.

Comment: This would belong on Code Review.

Comment: @EvanCarslake not quite. It's a pretty specific coding issue, and a clear question. Not a code review request.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB's [`plot`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function already allows you to do that in 2 different ways:

**1)** `plot(X1,Y1,...,Xn,Yn)` where `Xi`, `Yi` are vectors containing the corresponding `x` and `y` values. You can also add a `LineSpec` for each line: `plot(X1,Y1,LineSpec1,...,Xn,Yn,LineSpecn)`. In your case that would be:

```
plot(xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC)
```

**2)** `plot(Y)` where `Y` is a matrix containing all `y` values. This plots the columns vs. their row index. In your case:

```
plot([ A , B , C ])
```

or if your vectors `A`, `B`, `C` are row vectors:

```
plot([ A.' , B.' , C.' ])
```